# Right click stop propagation

Tags: javascript

How do I stop the propagation for right click events in javascript, so parent elements do not detect them at all?
When I click the link in the following html, left clicks are not detected, but right clicks are detected by the document element as 'click' events instead of 'contextmenu' events. I've tried to attach event listeners to mousedown, contextmenu, but to no success.

[EDIT] Changing the code to contextmenu works on chrome but not firefox (v23.0.1), this is probably a firefox bug.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.8">

function log(s){
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+=s+'<br/>';
}

window.onload=function(){
    document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        log('click detected');
    },false);

    let link=document.querySelector('a#link');
    //click only cares about left clicks
    link.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    },false);
};

</script>
</head>

<body>

<a id="link" href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>

<div id="log"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you looking to disable right click on link?

Comment: No, I want the context menu to still show up, but the event should not propagate to any parent element.

Comment: What event are you trying to stop propagating, `contextmenu`?

Comment: Any click (left or right click) event.

Comment: I've just run into the same problem, trying to prevent right-clicks from propagating. Firefox versions 25, 29, and 31 all have this behaviour where right-clicks produce a click event on the document which can't be stopped by `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: running into same problem in firefox v44. Has it got a fix?

Answer (score 3):

The 'right click' event is called the 'contextmenu' event.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html

---

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script>

function log(s){
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+=s+'<br/>';
}

window.onload=function(){
        document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                log('click detected');
        },false);

        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
                log('right-click detected');
        }, false);

        var link=document.querySelector('a#link');

        link.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
        },false);

        link.addEventListener('contextmenu',function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
        },false);
};

</script>
</head>

<body>

<a id="link" href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>

<div id="log"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried that (see my post), and it didn't work, can you provide an example if you got it working?

Comment: (lol @ downvote) I don't know why I bother sometimes, really I don't...  The right-click event _is_ the contextmenu event, really it is... really really!!!

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, this is apparently a firefox bug, I've tested it on firefox 23.0.1, your code works on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome won't execute script tags, including a version , for some reason, so i replaced `let` with `var`...

Stopping the propagation of  a `contextmenu` event triggered from `a#Link` to `document` works fine for me, in **Chrome** and **Firefeox**, here is the example i used.

**Edit**

---

> the contextmenu events are detected by the document element as click events instead.

In this case you can use a *mousedown* event, and add the condition `event.which === 3`

I updated the example, and added an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/erOkUJa/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>
<body>

<a id="link" href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a> 
<div id="log"></div>

<script type="application/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
  var link = document.querySelector('a#link');

  function log(s) {
      document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += s + '<br/>';
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
      var src = e.target || e.srcElement;
      log((src.nodeName === 'A' ? 'bubbled' : 'direct') + ' contextmenu on document detected');
    }
  }, false);

  link.addEventListener("mousedown", propagate);

  function propagate(e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
      log("contextmenu on link, propagating");
      link.removeEventListener("mousedown", propagate);
      link.addEventListener("mousedown", nopropagate);
    }
  }

  function nopropagate(e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
      log("contextmenu on link, nopropagating");
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now rightclicking in the following order gives us these outputs.

1. rightclick on document
   [image]
2. rightclick on link (propagates on first click)
   [image]
3. rightclick on link (doesn't propagate)
   [image]

*Screenshots are from Firefox 20.0*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited my question so it is clearer. Indeed, stopping the propagation of contextmenu events do work, however, on firefox 23.0.1, the contextmenu events are detected by the document element as click events instead.

Comment: The firefox bug is confirmed, I think you're mis-reading my question, but thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: still isn't fixed in firefox.