# stopPropagation() not working for right click in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm facing a weird issue in firefox . stopPropagation() not working for right click in firefox in my code but if I use  an alert or breakpoint before the code it will work. it working smoothly in ie,safari,chrome,opera my code is given below

jquery

```
$("#div-login").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

then this

```
$("#div-login").mousedown(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

and this too

```
    $("#div-login").click(function (e) {
     if(e.button ===2)
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

markup

```
<div="div-login">
  <fieldset>
         ---markup----
                        </fieldset>
</div>
```

but none of the above code is working for right click in firefox but working without a problem for left-click

I couldn't find out the problem please help....

Comment: Check this one, it may answer your question



  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676412/right-click-stop-propagation

Answer (score 1):

try [contextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu), like:

```
$('#div-login').on("contextmenu",function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

or

```
$('#div-login').on("click",function(e){
   if(e.which == 3) {  //right click
       e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

Comment: nope not working , I tried Both

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the contextmenu event

```
$("#div-login").on('contextmenu',function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k8Cmd/)

Also see: [Can't use jquery's click event handler to detect right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343117/cant-use-jquerys-click-event-handler-to-detect-right-click)

Comment: nope still not working

Answer (score 0):

***HTML***

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="div-login"></div>
</div>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('#div-login').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    if(e.button == 2 ) e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#box').on('mousedown', function () {
    alert('Right');
});
```

Works fine for me in FF and Chrome

[DEMO with stopPropagation()](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RS5XA/9/)

[DEMO without stopPropagation()](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RS5XA/10/)